# Cobertura test coverage does not cover tests which extend class under test

Tags: java, testing, code-coverage, junit4, cobertura

I have a class which I need to test eg. MyClass.java

I am using Junit4 so in order to test the protected methods as well in MyClass.java I create a test class MyClassTest.java (which is in a completely different package hence the inability to test the protected method otherwise).

I have written tests for all methods in MyClass and MyClassTest succeeds when run.

When I run the Cobertura test coverage for all classes in the project, this works fine and I get varying coverage from 0-100% according to tests written.

Cobertura reports however that MyClass has 0% coverage as it was not tested - it was infact the subclass that was tested.

Is there any way of making Cobertura pick up the fact that all methods being tested are within the parent class and picking that up as coverage??

Thanks